# mongoose query doesn't return the actual object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have added a method to my mongoose scheme. When I create an instance, I can call that object but when I query for that object and try to call the same method, it returns exception.

User.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
    surname: String
});

userSchema.methods.print = function() {
    console.log(this.name, this.surname);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

The following code works as expected:

```
const user = new User({});
user.print();
```

But when I query mongodb and try to call print on the method it returns exception:

```
User.findById(id, function(err,user){
    // print is not a function
    user.print();
});
```

I can't see where I'm making mistake,

And suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you haven't created an object of `User`.

Change `module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);` to `let User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);` in the `User.js` file and create an object of User before calling the print method, like:

`let User = require('<path>/User.js');` where you need to update `path` with the actual path of the file.